# Powershell script to get Azure Data factory Pipeline Run Details

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

I am working on Powershell script which retrieves all the Azure Data Factory Pipelines runs status in past 24 hours with starttime and endtime.

I have came across cmdlet like below

**Get-AzDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -DataFactoryName "XYZ" -ResourceGroupName "abc"  -LastUpdatedAfter "2023-12-19" -LastUpdatedBefore "2023-12-21"**

But above command not working properly , Anyone has pointers to specific command which i can use within Powershell to get this information.

Any information related to this appreciated .

looking for something like below

PipelinerunID  PipelineName Starttime EndTime  Trigger_Name

Answer (score 1):

Use [AzDataFactoryV2PipelineRun](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.DataFactoryV2/0.5.12) to get the Pipelines runs status in past 24 hours with start time and end time.

It will not return the Trigger name it only returns the below values in output

[image]

**Use below Command:**

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun -ResourceGroupName "resource group name" -DataFactoryName "datafactory name" -LastUpdatedAfter (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) -LastUpdatedBefore (Get-Date)
```

**Output:**

[image]

To get information about trigger run use this Command [Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2TriggerRun](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-powershell/blob/main/azurermps-6.13.0/AzureRM.DataFactoryV2/Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2TriggerRun.md)